# Storing Variables in "Loops" and Point Plotting

Tags: plotting, numerics, special-functions

Given the function $y=\sin x$ defined over the region $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$, I need to implement a "do loop" such that I sweep over 100 or so points $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ and find precisely the two $x$ values which map to this $y$ under $\sin x$.  For example, with $y=1/8$, I have the following code:

```
 NSolve[Sin[x] == 1/8 && -Pi <= x <= Pi, x, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

which outputs:

> ```
> {{x -> 0.12532783116806539687}, {x -> 3.0162648224217278416}}
> ```

Given these two points, call them $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ I want to plot a point $f(1/8) = |x_{1}-x_{2}|$.  In other words, I want to sweep over 100 or so $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ and plot $|x_{1}-x_{2}|$ at each of these points.

So, I'm wondering what the most efficient way to do this would be?  In particular, I'm worried about storing the variables

```
 {{x -> 0.12532783116806539687}, {x -> 3.0162648224217278416}}
```

How can I store these variables within the loop or how would I call them?  Perhaps the loop can output an array of my $y$ values and an array of $|x_{1}-x_{2}|$ values and I can trivially plot them from there?

#### Edit

So for my actual case of interest I have a function which essentially looks similar in form to $\sin x$, but is messier:

$$\lambda(x) = -\frac{1}{2}\frac{\theta'_{3}(\pi\, x\ |\ \tau)}{\theta_{3}(\pi\, x\ |\ \tau)}$$

Where these are the Jacobi theta functions.  *Mathematica* takes the input `EllipticTheta[3, Pi*x, Exp[I*Pi*tau]]`. Like I said, this behaves similarly to $\sin$ over the region $[-1/2,1/2]$.  So, what I'd like to do is, for a given $\tau$ that won't change, sweep through values $a \in [-\lambda_{\rm{max}}, \lambda_{\rm{max}}]$ and for each such value, find the two $x$ values which map to $a$ under $\lambda(x)$.

Given these two numbers, call them $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, I then would like to compute,

$\quad \quad \wp(2x_{1} + 1 + \tau \ | \ 1,\, \tau)-\wp(2x_{2}+1+\tau \ | \ 1,\, \tau)$

I'm getting comfortable with `NSolve` and `FindMax`, but sweeping over 100 or so $a \in [-\lambda_{\rm{max}},\, \lambda_{\rm{max}}]$ and storing and plotting, that's way over my head!

Comment: Try to avoid explicit looping in Mathematica. Use list operations instead. See for example http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18396/193

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @belisarius My apologies, I'll stay on top of that in the future.  Am new here.

Comment: spietro: it is commendable that you tried to present your problem using a simpler, minimal case. Maybe you could also expand on the actual problem you are working on, as you hinted in the comments, that includes a Weierstrass-P function, to make sure that the solutions proposed are actually applicable to your real problem.

Comment: @MarcoB Thank you, I added an edit to my original question!

Comment: @spietro  It's very difficult to answer your edit without concrete functions.

Comment: Those things defining $\lambda(x)$ are the Jacobi Theta Functions.  Does that help?

Comment: @spietro And again, post the Mathematica expression for $\lambda(x)$

Comment: Please stop posting TeX unless necessary. It doesn't help

Comment: It is given by, `-(1/2)*(EllipticThetaPrime[3, Pi*x, Exp[I*(1+I)*Pi]])/(EllipticTheta[3, 
    Pi*x, Exp[I*(1+I)*Pi]])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26321/discussion-between-spietro-and-belisarius).

Comment: @bel, on the other hand, sometimes the formulae are easier to parse/keep track of in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Cases[Quiet@{#, 
      Abs[Subtract @@ (x /. 
          NSolve[Sin[x] == # && -Pi <= x <= Pi, x,  WorkingPrecision -> 20])]} & /@ 
                                                                Range[-1, 1, 2/100], 
      {_Rational, _Real}] // ListPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course you may do

```
Plot[Abs[Subtract @@ (x /. Solve[Sin[x] == y && -Pi <= x <= Pi, x])], {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or even better:

```
Plot[Pi - Abs@ArcSin@y, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**

Based on our [chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26321/discussion-between-spietro-and-belisarius), this is my best guess on what you want:

```
f[x_, t_] := -EllipticThetaPrime[3, Pi x, Exp[I t Pi]]/
                   EllipticTheta[3, Pi x, Exp[I t Pi]]/2
t1 = I/4;
xf = NArgMax[{f[x, t1], 0 < x < 1}, x];
inv = WeierstrassInvariants[{1, t1}];
f1[x_, t_] := WeierstrassP[2 x + 1 + t, inv]


pt[val_] := f1[(x /. FindRoot[f[x, t1] == val, {x, 0}]), t1] - 
            f1[(x /. FindRoot[f[x, t1] == val, {x, 0.5}]), t1]

Plot[pt[x], {x, 0, xf}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you; I came up with a simpler example so as to explain my problem easier above.  If I actually want to take the difference of Weierstrass-$\wp$ at the two points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ we find, is that easy to generalize to?  Can I replace your `Subract` with a more concrete functional form?

Comment: @spietro What is your simpler example? I don't get you.

Comment: @belisarius I think OP means that the `Sin[x]` function discussed in his question *is* the simpler example he had come up with, but his real target function is Weierstrass-P.

Comment: @MarcoB But `Weierstrass-P` is an even function and Mathematica already has `InverseWeierstrassP` ... so I still don't get it :)

Comment: @belisarius Agreed (and +1 for exploring multiple methods of attack!). I wonder if OP had not realized the existence of `InverseWeierstrassP`, or the implication of your example with `ArcSin`. Anyway, hopefully OP will make his meaning more apparent...

Comment: @belisarius Indeed, I meant that $\sin$ was supposed to be a simpler example.  I added an edit above.  Thanks!

Comment: @Marco and bel, the branch cut structure of $\wp^{(-1)}$ is slightly messier than that of $\arcsin$, tho. At worst, OP may have to do everything in terms of `EllipticF[]`. The prospect is algebraically tear-inducing…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. I added the Special-Functions tag to attract your kind attention. I believe something wasn't fluid enough in this communication

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not look like one of the things I can resolve in one sitting. I'll look into it when I have a clear head and a ream of letter-size paper nearby.

Comment: @belisarius Your recent updates are oh so close to exactly what I need.  I've been mucking around for the last hour or so trying to figure out how to make your code use `NSolve` instead of `FindRoot` because this function is periodic so when you say find a root near 0 or 1/2, it's finding the one out of the range $-1/2 < x < 1/2$.  I keep getting ugly errors like "Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients," when I try to use `NSolve.'  Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: My code is `pts = {x /. NSolve[f[x, I/4] == # && -1/2 <= x <= 1/2, x, Reals]} & /@
    rr;` and from this I get errors

Answer (score 2):

You can get the set, these are ordered pairs, as you describe $(y,|x_2-x_1|)$ with the code:

```
Table[{y, 
Abs[Differences[
 x /. NSolve[Rationalize[Sin[x] == y] && -Pi <= x <= Pi, x, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20]]][[1]]}, {y, -.99, .99, .01}]
```

The only problem is that over this interval, there is only one solution at $y=\pm 1$. You see I have omitted those two values. The output here is just a table. Plot with `ListPlot[ ]`.